# Is this a rigorous mathematical proof that $P(A\times B)\neq P(A)\times P(B)$?

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

> I have to prove that $P(A\times B)\neq P(A)\times P(B)$

My approach:

I am showing that the cardinality of $P(A\times B)$ and $P(A)\times P(B)$ is not the same. I think this method works because powerset of a set is a set and for equality of two sets, it is mandatory for the sets to have the same elements.

Let, $A, B$ be two finite sets with $x,y$ elements respectively.

Thus no of elements in $P(A\times B)$ is $2^{xy}$ and no of elements in $P(A)\times P(B)=2^{x+y}$.

Let,$x=1,y=2$. Clearly, $2^{x+y}\neq 2^{xy}$.

Thus the two sets don't have the same number of elements. So we have successfully built a counterexample that the two sets contain some dissimilar elements (since their cardinality is different).

Is this a proper rigorous mathematical proof?

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: I guess, you just have proved that $P(A\times B)=P(A)\times P(B)$ is wrong,but you haven’t proved $P(A\times B)\neq P(A)\times P(B)$.

Comment: That's ok _if_ $A$ and $B$ are _finite_. If they're both infinite then $xy=x+y$. It's much easier than this!

Comment: @YanPeng I have to admit that I can't see your point, even from the darkest logician POV.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier I mean, maybe “for all $A,B$” is omitted in the question, so he just have disproved that $P(A\times B)=P(A)\times P(B)$ for all $A,B$ by builting a counter example.

Comment: He didn't disprove that if $|A| = |B|=2$ and $2^{2+2} = 2^{2*2}$ nor for any infinite sets.  If all that was required was to prove it isn't always true (versus is always not true) then a single counter example would do.

Comment: Are you sure that question was even *asked*.  $\emptyset \in P(M)$ always.  And $\emptyset \not \in J \times K$ ever.  So $P(M) \ne J\times X$ ever.

Comment: @fleablood The exact statement is-"Let A, B be sets. Is it true that..."

Comment: The simple answer is "no". Your proof is valid but overkill.  Simply pointing out that data structures are completely different and despite *looking* good, the statement is naive and once interpreted as to what it is *means*, is naive almost to the point of nonsense would be a more appropriate.  Your proof is bit akin to proving that a triangle can never be prime.

Comment: @fleablood what is "data structure"?

Comment: I mean $P(A\times B)$ is a class of subsets, the elements of the subsets are ordered pairs $(a,b)$ where $a\in A$ and $b\in B$..  $P(A)\times P(B)$ is set of ordered pairs $(\omega, \tau)$ were $\omega$ and $\tau$ are sets.  These are *utterly* different things!

Comment: Maybe *I'm* being overkill but $P(A\times B) = \{W_\alpha|W_\alpha = \{(a,b)|a\in E_\alpha,b\in F_\alpha\}$ for some $E_\alpha\subset A;F_\alpha\subset B\}$ whereas $P(A)\times P(B)=\{(\omega,\tau)|\omega\subset A,\tau\subset B\}$.  These aren't even remotely the same things at all. If $x\in P(A\times B)$ then $x=\{(a_i,b_j),(a_k,b_j)......\}$ and if $y\in P(A)\times P(B)$ then $y=(\{a_i,a_j,a_k...\},\{b_m,b_n,....\})$.  $x$ is a set of ordered pairs.  $y$ is an ordered pair of sets.  They are can't be equal because they are completely different *things*.

Comment: @fleablood Thanks. Your comment s are the best explanation.. even better than the answers perhaps when it comes to explicit explanation :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated the problem is too obvious. An element of $P(A)\times P(B)$ is an ordered pair $(E,F)$ where $E\subset A$ and $F\subset B$, and that ordered pair is simply not a subset of $A\times B$. If the problem wasn't supposed to be *that* trivial, surely you're actually supposed to show that $$P(A\times B)\ne\{E\times F: E\in P(A), F\in P(B)\}.$$(It's very easy to simply  write down an element of one of those sets that's not an element of the other...)

Answer (score 2):

As said by D.C. Ullrich, the ''data structures'' are different and so equality cannot be proved. But one can show that there is no bijection between these sets (finite case only!) as they have different cardinality which you already indicated.

For instance, if $A=\{a\}$ and $B=\{b,c\}$, then 
$$P(A\times B) = P(\{(a,b),(a,c)\} = \{\emptyset, \{(a,b)\}, \{(a,c)\}, \{(a,b),(a,c)\}\}$$ 
while $P(A)=\{\emptyset,\{a\}\}$ and $P(B)=\{\emptyset,\{b\}, \{c\},\{b,c\}\}$ and so
$P(A)\times P(B) = \{(x,y)\mid x\in P(A),y\in P(B)\}$ contains for instance the pair $(\{a\},\{b,c\})$.

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ are infinite then the two sets have the same cardinality. (Think about $A=B=\Bbb Z$ for example...)

Comment: Right. There is no way around this. I've added this.

Comment: There's no way around it if we're  supposed to show they have different cardinaliities. But for the actual question there's no reason the cardinality should be relevant.

Answer (score 2):

$\emptyset \in P(A\times B)$ because $\emptyset \subset M$ for any set $M$ and so $\emptyset \in P(M)$ for any set $M$.

And $\emptyset \not \in P(A) \times P(B)$ because $\emptyset \not \in J \times K$ for any sets $J$ and $K$ since $\emptyset$ is *not* an ordered pair of *anything*.

Now $\emptyset = \{\}$ and $\emptyset \ne (j,k)$ for any $j,k$s in any set whatsoever.  $(j,k)$ is an ordered pair and the empty set is not an ordered pair.  It simply isn't.  The empty set is not a number; it is not a pair of numbers; it's not a pair of elephants; it's not a pair of an elephant and a marble.  The empty set is not a pair of *anything*.

So $\emptyset \ne (j,k)$ for any $j$ in any set $J$ or any $k$ in any set $K$.  Even if $J = K =\emptyset$  we still do *not* have $\emptyset \in \emptyset \times \emptyset$.   $\emptyset \times \emptyset = \{(a,b)|a\in \emptyset; b\in \emptyset\}$ but there are no such $(a,b)$ because there is no $a\in \emptyset$ and there is no $b\in \emptyset$ so $\emptyset \times \emptyset = \{(a,b)|a\in \emptyset; b\in \emptyset\}=\emptyset$.  And $\emptyset \not \in \emptyset$.

So $\emptyset \in P(A\times B)$ but $\emptyset \not\in  P(A)\times P(B)$.  So $P(A\times B)$ can not ever equal $P(A)\times P(B)$.

.....

Also as $P(M)$ is a set of sets.  And $J\times K$ is a set of ordered pairs.  And sets are not ordered pairs and ordered pairs are not sets so these are two completely different types of things.